# Javascript - Print Blob Content Returned from API

Tags: javascript, rest, angular, typescript, printing

I'm building a page for my *angular2* web application where a user can select customers from a list and print off letters to mail them. These letters were uploaded as `PDFs` and are stored as `varbinary` in the database.

In the case of multiple selections, I'm simply appending byte[]'s so the user will print one document containing all of the letters to send to customers.

I'm able to pull the blob successfully from the API and return it with the content type `application-pdf` but then I don't know what to do with it from there.

**Here's my Angular2 Component API Call:**

```
this.printQueueService.getPrintContent(printRequests) //customers to receive letters
            .subscribe((data: Blob) => {
                var element: HTMLIFrameElement = <HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById('printFile');
                element.innerText = data + ""; //what do I do with the blob?
                element.contentWindow.print();
});
```

**HTML Element:**

```
<iframe id="printFile" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

I know I can just download the PDF and prompt the user to print using a PDF Viewer, but I'd rather not force users to go through extra steps.

I'd also rather not try to render the PDF in the browser and print because it assumes users have the proper plugins and browsers support it.

*What options do I have for printing a blob in the browser?*

Comment: you could use it as part of the src of the iframe.

Comment: even better. don't design your api that way - use a request in the iframe to get the pdf otherwise its a lot of extra memory for your js context to process.

Comment: @DanielA.White How would I make a post request to the API in an IFrame? The PDFs are dynamically generated.

Comment: do your post but return a url that the iframe can use.

Comment: Oh so the javascript `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`?

Comment: that would be the first way yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per suggestions from *Daniel A. White*, I solved this issue. I decided not to use an IFrame because these print files could be massive and the `print()` function includes the page name as footnotes.

Instead, I chose to open the generated PDF in a new tab as follows:

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
     window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, "PrintedLetters.pdf"); //IE is the worst!!!
}
else {
     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
     var a: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement('a');
     a.href = fileURL;
     a.target = '_blank';
     document.body.appendChild(a);
     a.click();
}
```